# Android Progaurd rules package names regex

Tags: android, android-r8

I need to add my Json Model data classes to progaurd rules.

But my model classes are located in several packages.
Eg., assume model classes are present in the following locations

```
com.app.user.model.User
com.app.user.model.Profile
com.app.music.model.Song
com.app.music.model.Playlist
com.app.social.model.Media
.
.
.
```

I need to exclude all of the model class files alone

all model class resembles a pattern `com.app.*.model.**`

Is there any way to exclude all these files in a single rule?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the same pattern as I mentioned in the question.

`-keep class com.app.*.model.** { *; }`